# Is there a way to create scales with domains that have a sub-domain?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a Manhattan plot, similar to the one seen below.  What I have, so far, is followed.

This is what I'm trying to create:
[image: This is what I'm trying to create]

This is what I've coded up so far (lol):

[image: This is what I've coded up so far.]

There are two factors that determine the `x` position of the dots.  (1)The chromosome index which ranges from `[1, 22]`, and (2)the position coordinate which ranges from `[1, 10,000,000]`.  The greater the chromosome index, the greater the position coordinate.

The question is: how do I set the domain for the position coordinates so that the dots stay within the chromosome index boundary like seen in the first picture.

Here is some relevant code:

```
var x0 = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]),
    x1 = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]),
     y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
 xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x0).orient("bottom"),
 yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickPadding(6),
 color = d3.scale.category20c();

var positions = [],
    pvalues = [];
this.data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.values.forEach(function (v) {
        positions.push(v.position);
        pvalues.push(v.pvalue);
    });
});

var xMax = d3.max(positions),
    ymax = d3.max(pvalues);

x0.domain([1, 22]);
x1.domain([0, xMax]);
y.domain([0, ymax]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 8)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("p-value");

var chromosome = svg.selectAll(".chr")
    .data(this.data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "chr")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x0(d.chr);
    })
    .attr("width", width / 22)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.chr);
    });

chromosome.selectAll("circle")
    .data(function (d) {
        return d.values;
    })
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 3)
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return x1(d.position);
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return y(d.pvalue);
    });
```

**Update:** So I switched to using `d3.scale.ordinal()` for both `x` scales by following the [grouped barchart example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051).  I think I got closer but, now, how do I prevent the dots from being drawn in the same `x` position?
[image]

**Data format**:

`this.data`:

```
[
  {
    chr: 1,
    values: [
      {
        snp: rs182799,
        position: 1478180,
        pvalue: 3.26E-05
      },
      {
        snp: rs182349,
        position: 1598180,
        pvalue: 3.26E-05
      },
    ...
    ]
  },

  chr: 2,
    values: [
      {
        snp: rs199799,
        position: 2678180,
        pvalue: 3.26E-05
      },
      {
        snp: rs182349,
        position: 2998180,
        pvalue: 3.26E-05
      },
    ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving to ordinal scale was the right thing to do for the primary domain `[1, 22]`.

For the subdomain of `[1, 1e7]` for each *primary abscissa*, the way to do it would be to generate one scale for each abscissa. A few questions about the range should be answered first, though:

1. Are the `positions` uniformly distributed?
2. In the primary chart, it looks as if the `range` of the subdomain is shrinking as the primary abscissa is increasing (e.g., the width of area for `x = 22` is much smaller than for `x = 2`). Do `position` for each chromosome index have the same range `[1, 1e7]`?

Assuming that the `position` is distributed uniformly in `[1, 1e7]` and the maximum value of `position` is `1e7` for all chromosome indexes (which does not seem to be the case), the way to do it would be to `nudge` the `x` axis value of each circle within the subdomain:

```js
chromosome.selectAll("circle")
    // ...
    .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
        /* Assuming that data provided is in the "correct" order
         * and `x1` is the ordinal scale. 
         */
        return x1(i) - x1.rangeBand() / 2 + d.position / 1e7;
    })
    // ...
```

Here the `scale` of the subdomain is an implicit one, not a `d3.scale`.

Answer (score 1):

`xMax` is 22, so you won't get any dots on a line other than the members of the enumeration from 1 to 22. The objects in `this.data` have a maximum `value.position` of 22 which means you're using the chromosome value to determine `position`. In reality you want to use a very fine-grained `position` value (from 1 to 10000000) to determine the actual x position of the dot, but only display the numbers 1 to 22 on the graph front-end. As far as I can tell this is the issue.

It would help if we could see what `this.data` refers to.

Comment: What happens if you change `xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x0)` to `xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x1)`?

Comment: That only changes the visible axis.  I don't think it has anything to do with the domain of the scale and how the values are mapped to it.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. I am not an expert on d3, but I'd try to get the data mapped out according to `x1` then use native javascript or some custom method to recolor the dots to the correct values if they're within the acceptable range. Then you can deal with the display of the axis later.